# Emacs shell mode showing unwanted char

Tags: eshell, terminal-emacs

my emacs shell mode screen shot ...

[image: emacs shell mode screen]

Normal shell looks like this...

[image: shell mode normal]

I have .emacs file empty..

emacs version 24.5.1

I already tried this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663005/why-does-shell-mode-display-some-rubbish-code

[I copy the code provided in solution of above question in my .emacs file but its not working for me...]

Comment: This is two separate issues, one being a too fancy prompt that you'll need to deactivate inside Emacs, the other being bracketed paste where you need to know the shell to deactivate it.

Comment: I am new to emacs .....can you tell me how to do this in little more details ....or any link .....

Comment: First you'll have to tell us what shell you're using.

Comment: OS Ubuntu 16.04      Shell : zsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something along the following to your `.zshrc`:

```
if [[ $TERM == dumb ]]; then
  PROMPT=<normal stuff>
  unset zle_bracketed_paste
else
  PROMPT=<fancy stuff>
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to .zshrc file

```
# turn off ZLE bracketed paste in dumb term
# otherwise turn on ZLE bracketed-paste-magic
if [[ $TERM == dumb ]]; then
   unset zle_bracketed_paste
else
   autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
   zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic
fi
```